# Mysql Complex Where Clause

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I really surprised when I tried below code in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE (key='free_shipping' and value='yes') 
  AND (key='price' and value='5')
```

It doesn't work. I need to get product that is both **free_shipping** is 'yes' AND **price** equal '5' at the same time. How can I create this query properly?

**Table Structure:**

*contents:* (TABLE 1)

```
CONTENT_ID   TITLE  DESCRIPTION  DATE
```

*content_fields:*  (TABLE 2)

```
FIELD_ID   CONTENT_ID    KEY_NAME    VALUE
```

Example *(Get product that has 1 ID and its shipping is FREE)*:

```
SELECT *  FROM `contents` as c LEFT JOIN `content_fields` as cf ON  c.content_id = cf.content_id WHERE c.content_id = 1 AND  cf.key_name = 'free_shipping' AND cf.value = 'yes'
```

Comment: Is key member of the table "table"? key can't be both "free_shipping" and "price".

Comment: If your `table` only consits of key-values and is used for "real" data storage, it seems like a big design problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your current query is contradictory as a single row can never match the WHERE clause. I assume you want something like this.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM table 
WHERE (key='free_shipping' and value='yes') or (key='price' and value='5')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT key) = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
WHERE free_shipping='yes' AND price='5'
```

or:

```
WHERE free_shipping=yes AND price=5
```

if the fields aren't strings

Comment: @halfdan - I don't agree he has. I think the OP is asking how to do a relational division query on an EAV type table.

Comment: no, it doesn't work :( because free_shipping and price are not field, they're values.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets don't change the meaning of this statement. Without them you have:

```
key='free_shipping' and value='yes' and key='price' and value='5'
=>
key='free_shipping' and key='price'
=>
nothing!
```

try `WHERE free_shipping='yes' AND price='5'`

**edit**:
scrap that, I'm now completely confused by your table. Is it just a load of key/value pairs? Could we see the table structure?

Comment: You can check above for table structure

Answer (score 1):

To get product titles that have free shipping and worth 5.......
select distinct x.TITLE
from
contents x, content_fields y, content_fields z 
where
x.CONTENT_ID = y.CONTENT_ID and
y.CONTENT_ID = z.CONTENT_ID and
y.key_name = 'free_shipping' and y.value='yes' and
z.key_name = 'price' and z.value='5'